# How do I add specific requirements to this recursive hashtag generator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, recursion

I'm trying to build a hashtag generator with one specific requirement. The function below works well but I want to **exclude all hashtags that are comprised of just one word**. This is a brain teaser I just can't wrap my mind around.

```
function hashtag(string) {
  var words = string.split(" ");
  var result = [];
  var f = function(prefix, words) {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        result.push(prefix + words[i]);
        f(prefix + words[i], words.slice(i + 1));
    }
  };
  f('#', words);
  return result;
}
```

Running `hashtag("Golden Gate Bridge");` will produce...

```
[ '#Golden', '#GoldenGate', '#GoldenGateBridge', '#GoldenBridge', '#Gate', '#GateBridge', '#Bridge' ]
```

I would like it to produce...

```
['#GoldenGate', '#GoldenGateBridge', '#GoldenBridge', '#GateBridge']
```

Note that all the single word origin hashtags are gone.

I tried adding in a "depth" variable that incremented with each additional level of recursion and tried some "if" statements but couldn't find the right combination.

Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right path adding a depth counter.

```
function hashtag(string) {
  var words = string.split(" ");
  var result = [];
  var f = function(prefix, words, depth) {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        // Only add this hashtag if our prefix depth is > 1
        if (depth > 1) {
            result.push(prefix + words[i]);
        }

        // Increase the prefix depth with each iteration.
        f(prefix + words[i], words.slice(i + 1), depth + 1);
    }
  };

  // Pass the default depth
  f('#', words, 1);
  return result;
}
```

You can see this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/3Kgzf/